# MySQL 5.5 starts and then instantly stops

Tags: 10.10, mysql

MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 10.10 used to work well until yesterday but today whenever I start MySQL using `mysqld_safe` as root user it shows

```
Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

and then shows `pid ended`

I haven't run any updates recently but I used the MySQL administrator to connect to a remote database but MySQL administrator was installed one month ago.

I then examined the error file *error.log* and found this:

```
120210 02:33:23 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
120210  2:33:23 [Warning] Ignoring user change to '=root' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

120210  2:33:23 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/errmsg.sys'
120210  2:33:23 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120210  2:33:23 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120210  2:33:23 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
120210  2:33:23 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
120210  2:33:23 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120210  2:33:23 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120210  2:33:23 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120210  2:33:24  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120210  2:33:25 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120210  2:33:25 [ERROR] Aborting

120210  2:33:25  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120210  2:33:26  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
120210  2:33:26 [Note]
120210 02:33:26 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/lovesh-Inspiron-N4050.pid ended
```

EDIT:
as asked by Huckle the `ps -aux` goes like this

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2884  1740 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:01 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:06 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [migration/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [watchdog/0]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [migration/1]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:04 [ksoftirqd/1]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [watchdog/1]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [migration/2]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:06 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [watchdog/2]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [migration/3]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:03 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [watchdog/3]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [events/0]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [events/1]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [events/2]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [events/3]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [cpuset]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [khelper]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [netns]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [pm]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [sync_supers]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [bdi-default]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kintegrityd/0]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kintegrityd/1]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kintegrityd/2]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kintegrityd/3]
root        31  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kblockd/0]
root        32  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kblockd/1]
root        33  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kblockd/2]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kblockd/3]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kacpid]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kacpi_notify]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kacpi_hotplug]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ata_aux]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ata_sff/0]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ata_sff/1]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ata_sff/2]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ata_sff/3]
root        43  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [khubd]
root        44  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kseriod]
root        45  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kmmcd]
root        46  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [khungtaskd]
root        47  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kswapd0]
root        48  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Feb09   0:00 [ksmd]
root        49  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [aio/0]
root        50  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [aio/1]
root        51  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [aio/2]
root        52  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [aio/3]
root        53  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthr]
root        54  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [crypto/0]
root        55  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [crypto/1]
root        56  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [crypto/2]
root        57  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [crypto/3]
root        62  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [pciehpd]
root        64  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kstriped]
root        65  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kmpathd/0]
root        66  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kmpathd/1]
root        67  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kmpathd/2]
root        68  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kmpathd/3]
root        69  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kmpath_handle]
root        70  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ksnapd]
root        71  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:12 [kondemand/0]
root        72  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:10 [kondemand/1]
root        73  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:10 [kondemand/2]
root        74  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:07 [kondemand/3]
root        75  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kconservative]
root        76  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kconservative]
root        77  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kconservative]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kconservative]
root       298  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root       309  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root       310  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       312  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [scsi_eh_3]
root       318  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:01 [scsi_eh_4]
root       319  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [scsi_eh_5]
root       337  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [scsi_eh_6]
root       338  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:04 [usb-storage]
root       356  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [jbd2/sda3-8]
root       357  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwr]
root       358  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwr]
root       359  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwr]
root       360  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [ext4-dio-unwr]
root       392  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [flush-8:0]
root       422  0.0  0.0   2524   872 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 upstart-udev-br
root       424  0.0  0.0   2624  1016 ?        S<s  Feb09   0:00 udevd --daemon
root       621  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [kpsmoused]
root       868  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [i915]
root       908  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [hci0]
syslog     958  0.0  0.0  34600  1140 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 rsyslogd -c4
root       959  0.0  0.0   5636  2212 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
102        999  0.0  0.0   3576  1948 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:02 dbus-daemon --s
avahi     1006  0.0  0.0   3012  1372 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 avahi-daemon: r
root      1007  0.0  0.1  19268  4340 ?        Ssl  Feb09   0:01 NetworkManager
avahi     1008  0.0  0.0   3012   440 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 avahi-daemon: c
root      1012  0.0  0.0   4432  2460 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/modem
root      1037  0.0  0.0   4328  2120 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:01 /usr/sbin/bluet
root      1051  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [l2cap]
root      1060  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb09   0:00 [kslowd000]
root      1061  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb09   0:00 [kslowd001]
root      1062  0.0  0.0   1856   560 tty4     Ss+  Feb09   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1066  0.0  0.0   1856   564 tty5     Ss+  Feb09   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1080  0.0  0.0   1856   560 tty2     Ss+  Feb09   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1081  0.0  0.0   1856   568 tty3     Ss+  Feb09   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1084  0.0  0.0   1856   564 tty6     Ss+  Feb09   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
root      1087  0.0  0.0   4904  2280 ?        S    Feb09   0:07 /sbin/wpa_suppl
root      1090  0.0  0.0   2112   960 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 acpid -c /etc/a
root      1095  0.0  0.0   2928   612 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:01 /usr/sbin/irqba
root      1104  0.0  0.0  19540  3224 ?        Ssl  Feb09   0:00 gdm-binary
root      1116  0.0  0.0   2024   636 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/inetd
root      1124  0.0  0.0  21192  3120 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/conso
root      1196  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 [hd-audio0]
root      1200  0.0  0.0  21536  3816 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gd
daemon    1201  0.0  0.0   2316   356 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 atd
root      1202  0.0  0.0   2456   904 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 cron
root      1215  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb09   0:00 [krfcommd]
root      1216  0.0  0.0  13300  1460 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbi
root      1271  8.8  0.8  63836 35016 tty7     Rs+  Feb09  18:52 /usr/bin/X :0 -
root      1313  0.0  0.0  13300   980 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/winbi
root      1337  0.0  0.0   6792  2512 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd
gdm       1378  0.0  0.0   3456   576 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-l
root      1410  0.0  0.0  20120  3276 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm/gd
root      1438  0.0  0.3  17564 12256 ?        S    Feb09   0:08 /usr/lib/upower
rtkit     1442  0.0  0.0  22992  1216 ?        SNl  Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/rtkit/
root      1446  0.0  0.1   6924  4220 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
root      1521  0.0  0.0   1856   564 tty1     Ss+  Feb09   0:00 /sbin/getty -8
gdm       1580  0.0  0.0  28296  3916 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
lovesh    1606  0.0  0.0  41380  2916 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
lovesh    1625  0.0  0.1  35848  7128 ?        Ssl  Feb09   0:00 gnome-session
lovesh    1656  0.0  0.0   3352   196 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-ag
lovesh    1659  0.0  0.0   3456   576 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-l
lovesh    1660  0.0  0.0   5004  2212 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:03 /bin/dbus-daemo
lovesh    1665  0.0  0.1   9232  4164 ?        S    Feb09   0:04 /usr/lib/libgco
lovesh    1666  0.0  0.3 155224 13608 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:01 gnome-power-man
lovesh    1674  0.0  0.3 100192 12096 ?        Ssl  Feb09   0:05 /usr/lib/gnome-
lovesh    1678  0.0  0.0   7540  2308 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
lovesh    1686  0.0  0.0  30644  2108 ?        Ssl  Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//
lovesh    1690  0.0  0.5 101212 23128 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/python
lovesh    1693  0.0  0.4  82704 18120 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:09 gnome-panel
lovesh    1694  0.0  0.3 154756 14296 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:11 /usr/bin/metaci
lovesh    1696  1.7  0.1 162168  7380 ?        S<sl Feb09   3:47 /usr/bin/pulsea
lovesh    1698  0.0  0.2  38464  9100 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/evolut
lovesh    1699  0.3  1.3 169024 54932 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:41 nautilus
lovesh    1701  0.0  0.1  19128  5872 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/policy
lovesh    1703  0.0  0.2  74540  9456 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 bluetooth-apple
lovesh    1706  0.0  0.4 161360 18504 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:05 nm-applet --sm-
lovesh    1709  0.0  0.0  27716  2836 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-
lovesh    1718  0.0  0.0  20688  3300 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/pulsea
lovesh    1729  0.0  0.0  52552  3592 ?        Ssl  Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/bonobo
lovesh    1734  0.0  0.0  34392  3672 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
root      1736  0.0  0.0  16356  3436 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/udisks
root      1737  0.0  0.0   5620  1004 ?        S    Feb09   0:03 udisks-daemon: 
lovesh    1745  0.1  0.3  80040 14816 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:23 /usr/lib/gnome-
lovesh    1747  0.0  0.2  77428 11272 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-
lovesh    1752  0.0  0.0   8180  2188 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
lovesh    1754  0.0  0.0  17976  2244 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
lovesh    1757  0.0  0.0   7788  3068 ?        S    Feb09   0:01 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
lovesh    1761  0.0  0.0  13452  2940 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/obex-d
lovesh    1768  0.0  0.4  93436 16356 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:03 /usr/lib/gnome-
lovesh    1769  0.0  0.3  88040 14280 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:04 /usr/lib/indica
lovesh    1770  0.0  0.2  31076  8980 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
lovesh    1771  0.0  0.3  86860 13416 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
lovesh    1782  0.0  0.0   7920  2512 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
lovesh    1784  0.0  0.1  26908  5180 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
lovesh    1787  0.0  0.0  15716  3648 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
lovesh    1788  0.0  0.1  87248  5304 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
lovesh    1794  0.0  0.1  29012  4640 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
lovesh    1796  0.0  0.1  18040  4120 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/indica
lovesh    1808  0.0  0.0   7440  2388 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/g
lovesh    1819  0.0  0.1  19124  6616 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-
lovesh    1835  0.0  0.3  31052 13028 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/bin/python
lovesh    1836  0.0  0.0   3896   248 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /bin/cat
lovesh    1840  0.0  0.4  31736 17032 ?        S    Feb09   0:01 /usr/bin/python
lovesh    1849  0.0  0.3  77124 12888 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:06 /usr/lib/notify
lovesh    2787  8.3  5.8 695972 236972 ?       Sl   Feb09  15:13 /usr/lib/firefo
lovesh    2868  0.8  0.5 112724 23436 ?        Sl   Feb09   1:32 /usr/lib/firefo
lovesh    3148  0.3  1.9 184408 78468 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:28 evince /home/lo
lovesh    3152  0.0  0.0  22316  2340 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:00 /usr/lib/evince
root      3645  0.0  0.3  56292 12484 ?        Ss   Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4133  0.0  0.3  56656 13152 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4134  0.0  0.3  56656 13152 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4136  0.0  0.2  56292 11880 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4153  0.0  0.4  58820 19716 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4160  0.0  0.3  56692 13260 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4161  0.0  0.3  56676 13176 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4162  0.0  0.3  56656 13372 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4163  0.0  0.4  57516 17028 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
lovesh    4675  0.1  0.4 135576 18392 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:09 geany /home/lov
lovesh    4676  0.0  0.0   2052   704 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 gnome-pty-helpe
lovesh    4677  0.0  0.0   7356  3900 pts/1    Ss+  Feb09   0:00 /bin/bash
daemon    4699  0.0  0.2  56292 11880 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
daemon    4701  0.0  0.2  56292 11620 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /usr/local/apac
root      5220  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Feb09   0:00 [kbnepd bnep0]
root      5222  0.0  0.0   2296  1020 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 /sbin/dhclient
lovesh    6307  0.0  0.3  95876 14756 ?        Sl   Feb09   0:05 gnome-terminal
lovesh    6310  0.0  0.0   2052   720 ?        S    Feb09   0:00 gnome-pty-helpe
```

also the `ls -lah /var/lib/mysql` goes like this

```
total 30M
drwx------  5 mysql root  4.0K 2012-02-09 23:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 74 root  root  4.0K 2011-12-17 10:31 ..
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  18M 2012-02-09 23:36 ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 5.0M 2012-02-09 23:36 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 5.0M 2011-11-14 23:44 ib_logfile1
drwx------  2 mysql root  4.0K 2011-11-14 23:44 mysql
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql  28K 2011-11-14 23:44 mysql-bin.000001
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 974K 2011-11-14 23:44 mysql-bin.000002
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql   38 2011-11-14 23:44 mysql-bin.index
drwx------  2 mysql mysql 4.0K 2011-11-14 23:44 performance_schema
drwx------  2 mysql root  4.0K 2011-11-14 23:44 test
```

here is the output of  `namei -lo /var/lib/mysql`

```
f: /var/lib/mysql
drwxr-xr-x root  root /
drwxr-xr-x root  root var
drwxr-xr-x root  root lib
drwx------ mysql root mysql
```

Comment: Can you output `ps -aux` while the thread is running and also `ls -lah /var/lib/mysql`? I'm interested in mysql's effective permissions.

Comment: @Huckle i posted the output of 2 commands you mentioned. what did you exactly mean by mysql "effective" permissions

Comment: loveh can you please post the output of `namei -lo /var/lib/mysql`

Comment: @MarcosRoriz i posted it

Comment: Where did you install mysql, e.g, /usr/share/mysql??

Comment: i installed it to /usr/local/mysql

Comment: lovesh, processes that are run as root can drop their elevated privileges after they start. Alternatively, using suid, users can start a process with different privilege levels than the owner. Effective privileges are the set that govern what access a process actually has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your log:

`120210  2:33:23 [ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/errmsg.sys'`

That seems to be the issue. Check to see if the file is there.

Check to see if the file `/usr/local/mysql/share/english/errmsg.sys` exists and then:

```
cp /usr/local/mysql/share/english/errmsg.sys /usr/share/errmsg.sys
```

Make sure the new /usr/share/errmsg.sys file has permissions for MySQL to access it and try restarting.

From the link above, it seems this just happened when the user restarted the machine. If your machine was rebooted, it might for some reason have deleted the file. Why would it do that? I have no idea, unfortunately.

Comment: the link is 404.

Comment: Thanks! I encounter the similar problem with mysqld_safe, but my error message direct me to : /share/mysql/errmsg.sys missing, so I just copy a file to here, and then the probem disappears. It's definitely a bug in mysqld_safe, but no one would like to debug it, it's really a pity.

Answer (score 12):

[I'm cross copying this post from superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/146337/install-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu-10-04), it basically fixes your problem.

I used The following guide to install 5.5 on Ubuntu 11.04: http://www.ovaistariq.net/490/a-step-by-step-guide-to-upgrading-to-mysql-5-5/

Everything worked perfectly except one of the final steps, launching mysql:

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql
```

Was giving me the following message and then shutting down:

```
[ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/errmsg.sys'
```

After some [googling](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=mysql%20%22%5BERROR%5D%20Can%27t%20find%20messagefile%20%27/usr/share/errmsg.sys%27%22) I found the [solution to be adding the following flag](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2010/09/30/#ubuntu-server.txt):

```
--lc-messages-dir="/usr/local/mysql/share/english/"
```

To launch it and have it actually work, I used the following command:

```
 mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --lc-messages-dir="/usr/local/mysql/share/english/"
```

MySQL 5.5 has some great new features that solved a partitioning issue for me; partitioning via a varchar.

Good luck!

Comment: For CentOS 7: `--lc-messages-dir="/usr/share/mysql/english/"`

Answer (score 2):

Better not copy files to the fallback directory. Instead, either specify the parameter in the command line, or add the following to `my.ini` / `my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
lc_messages_dir = /usr/local/mysql/share
```

More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-message-language.html).

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly this same problem in Debian 7.0 - Wheezy.

Upon MySql start, the system was trowing the error:

```
[ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys'
```

I did some investigating based on this post, and found out the file `/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys` was missing.

For me it was enough to install:

```
apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-core-5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL isn't setting its error message language to English automatically.  I have yet to figure out why this happens, but the solution is to pass `--lc-messages=english` (formerly `--language`) on the command line or add `language=english` to the configuration file.

The file specified in the error message should not exist: MySQL shouldn't be looking there.  If you copy a locale file to that location, you're not fixing the real problem; you're just asking for trouble down the road.